# Graph Theory Proof of Website Clicks

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Suppose we have n websites such that for every pair of websites $A$ and $B$, either $A$ has a link to $B$ or $B$ has a link to $A$. Prove or disprove that there exists a website that is reachable from every other website by clicking at most 2 links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the website with the most links.

Let $W$ be the website with the most links, suppose there is a website $V$ that can't be reached with $1$ or $2$ clicks from $W$.

Then this means if $W$ has a link to website $U$ then $V$ also has a link to website $U$.

Since $V$ also has a link to website $W$ we conclude $V$ has more links than $W$, a contradiction. The contradiction arises from supposing there is a website which can't be reached with $1$ or $2$ clicks from $W$, the result follows.

Comment: How does this prove my problem? Having trouble seeing how.

Comment: I'll write it again, maybe it will be clearer now

Comment: Wow. That's it? Maybe I was overthinking it. I was thinking about using induction.

Comment: Wait. Why did you say that "You want the website with the most links" Is that the assumption you make to prove by contradiction?

Comment: the website you are looking for is the website with the most links, this website can reach every other website with at most two clicks